# Extra space taking in ie7

Tags: html, css

I used a specific css for ie7 its getting problem in ie7 an unwanted white space is taking on right side its near about 50px; that's why an horizontally  scroll bar is displaying on page,
I want to remove a scrollbar and white space.

Code which i used in css of ie7

```
#pagewrap   /* This pagewrap is use for signup page to fixed align center */ 
{
    margin  : 0px auto;
    width   : 1000px;
    min-height  : 710px; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#pagewrap   /* This pagewrap is use for signup page to fixed align center */ 
{
    margin  : 0px auto;
    width   : 900px;
    min-height  : 710px; 
}
```

Try shrinking the width of the object if it is too wide.  You could also change to a percentage:

```
#pagewrap   /* This pagewrap is use for signup page to fixed align center */ 
{
    margin  : 0px auto;
    width   : 100%;
    min-height  : 710px; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Tommy i tried that also but its not working
Thats why i used this

Comment: Are you sure its not a parent div causing the issue or anything?  Try putting a border on this class and see where how it is actually displaying on the page.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```